# REACT JS: keep the position element in component after remove 1 element

Tags: reactjs

I want make a little drag-drop application, when i remove 1 element in state:
my state

```
render:

{.................} {...............} { play game}          
{..................} { makeup  } {..............}         
{sing a song} {..............} {...............}

but when i remove: makeup
this is my state:        
{.........} {................. } { play game }                                  
{.........} {sing a song} {...............}

i expect : 
{..................} {.............} { play game }        
{sing a song} {.............} {.................}
```

this is my code:

https://repl.it/@NguyenHai3/CreepyPrivateUpgrade

sorry because i can't copy for here =((
help !!!

Comment: can't see your code @ the url

Comment: @https://repl.it/@NguyenHai3/CreepyPrivateUpgrade

Comment: what does {................} mean in your question ?